# storing and printing out "a" vs 'a'

Tags: c, char

I understand if I do,

```
char a= 'a';//gets stored as a 1 byte char
```

And `"a"` means a 2 byte string with `\0` its last byte.

If I run-

```
int main(void) {
  char a= "a";
  printf("\n\r%c", a);
  return 0;
}
```

It outputs- @

and If I run

```
int main(void) {
  char a= 'a';
  printf("\n\r%c", a);
  return 0;
}
```

It outputs- a

I get as expected in the 2nd case, am just curious why am I getting @ in the 1st case?

Comment: Compile with warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A string is an array of characters. When an array is used as an r-value, it gets converted to a pointer to the first element. So when you do:

```
char a = "a";
```

you're storing the address of the string into `a`, not the first character. This is resulting in an implementation-dependent conversion from pointer to character, and the result you're seeing is because this results in the same character code as the `@` character. It will generally be unpredictable, because the address of the string depends on many factors.

It's equivalent to:

```
char *str = "a";
char a = str;
```

To get the first character into the `char` variable, the second line would have to be:

```
char a = *str;
```

Comment: perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because when you try this

```
char ch = "a";
```

you are trying to insert a string where in the second case you are using the format of inserting a single character. So it doesn't show any error.